# How can I apply auto smooth to more than 1 object at the same time

Tags: smooth

How can I apply auto smooth to more than 1 object at the same time. I have tried holding ALT while clicking the Auto Smooth checkbox in the Object properties tab but it does not work for Blender 3.0. Is there some change or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Before 3.0.1, Object Properties are related to the Active object only (one can see exactly which object is being affected on the top of the Properties Window). They do not act on the Selected Collection (not even if they are pinned). So the solution is to create a new operator to apply ```obj.data.use_auto_smooth``` and ```obj.data.auto_smooth_angle``` to all meshes in the Selection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the same thing as when you want to assign the same option or value to several objects: Select the objects, put the mouse over the *Auto Smooth* option box, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or click on the box while you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>).

Or select the object, at last shift select the object that has *Auto Smooth* enabled, right click on the option box and *Copy to Selected*.

Comment: Thank you. I was holding alt then clicking the checkbox, which did not work. I did not even know that you could toggle without clicking. Alt Enter instead of click was a little counter intuitive so I had not thought of it, but It is good to know! Also the right click on the checkbox and Copy to Selected worked great too! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

it does work with 3.0, as you can see in the gif.

Make sure you selected both objects before with shift-select on the other objects after you selected one object.

[image]

You can see in the gif in the lower right corner -> it is 3.0

i select both objects before -> auto smooth is off

i select both after -> both are on